# Rotate a refresh button image smoothly so that it completes to the nearest turn iOS

Tags: ios, ios7, cgaffinetransform, cabasicanimation

I am trying to animate a refresh button so that it rotates indicating that the refresh is in progress. It needs to be smooth so that if the refresh only takes  0.1 seconds we still do a complete rotation so the user can acknowledge something happened and that its a smooth transition. It should also continue rotating until i stop it however stopping shouldn't abruptly stop it only tell it to complete the current turn.

Originally i did something like this

```
CABasicAnimation *rotationAnimation;
rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:M_PI * 2.0 * 10];
rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
rotationAnimation.duration = 10;
[self.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
```

And stopping like so

```
[self.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

This Worked fine in the sense that the animation continued past 2pi radians smoothly, however when the refresh took less than 1/10 of the second it wouldnt look very smooth as the animation would get get 10% of the way round and then suddenly stop and the removeAllAnimations method resets the image back to its default.

I managed to get around this an alternative stop method

```
    CALayer *presentLayer = self.layer.presentationLayer;
    float currentAngle = [(NSNumber *) [presentLayer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"] floatValue];

    [self.layer removeAllAnimations];   

    if (currentAngle < 0) {
        currentAngle = 2 * ABS(currentAngle);
    }

    float rotationProgressPercent = currentAngle / (2 * M_PI);    
    CABasicAnimation *rotationAnimation;
    rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    rotationAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:currentAngle];
    rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:M_PI * 2];
    rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
    rotationAnimation.duration = 1 - rotationProgressPercent;
```

Basically I get the current angle of the rotation in radians, stop the animation and start a new animation from that position to two pi. I have to do some work with the duration to keep the speed constant, the speed aspect works fine but the problem is that somethings the animation has a very slight lag/twitch to it. I believe this is because the stop animation is asynchronously posting this request to the system (this is just speculation) and that my current angle is stale by the time i go to do my second animation.

Are there any other approaches i can try.

Answer (score 2):

So i eventually found a solution, how this is useful

```
-(void)startSpinning {
    if (animating) {
        return;
    }
    animating = YES;
    [self rotateViewWithDuration:1 byAngle:M_PI * 2];

}

- (void)stopSpinning {
    animating = NO;
}


- (void)rotateViewWithDuration:(CFTimeInterval)duration byAngle:(CGFloat)angle {


    [CATransaction begin];
    CABasicAnimation *rotationAnimation;
    rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    rotationAnimation.byValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:angle];
    rotationAnimation.duration = duration;
    rotationAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;

    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{

        if (animating) {
            [self rotateViewWithDuration:duration byAngle:angle];
        }
    }];

    [self.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```